# Removing array/object based from set of property and value dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Assuming I have an array of object lets say data

```
[ 
  0: { Name: "foo", X1 : "1", X2 : "1", Other : "Test1" },
  1: { Name: bar, X1 : "2", X2 : "2", Other : "Test2" },
  2: { Name: test, X1 : "2", X2 : "3", Other : "Test3" }
]
```

And I have another array of objects say fields

```
[
 0: { 
       rows: [ 
             { checked: true, value: "1", field: "X1"} ,
             {  checked: false, value: "2", field: "X1"} 
             ]
     }
 1: { 
       rows: [
             {  checked: false, value: "1", field: "X2"},
             {  checked: false, value: "2", field: "X2"},
             {  checked: false, value: "3", field: "X2"}
             ]
     }
]
```

How can I remove the data that has the "false" value in its property name. both fields and value should be dynamic and based from the example it should output:

```
[ 
  0: { Name: "foo", X1 : "1", X2 : "1", Other : "Test1" }
]
```

because its X1 = 2

I tried the following

```
FilterData( fields, data): object{
    let $result = datafile.filter(function (o) {
      return Object.keys(toRemove).every(function(k){
        return toRemove[k].some(function (f){
          return o[k] !== f;
        })
      })
    })
    return $result;
  }
```

but got an error "toRemove[k].some is not a function", I'm using angular and typescript

Comment: Which example data corresponds to which variable in your code? If the top example is `datafile`, then please label it as such in your question. Also, I see nothing that has "false" in the property name. Do you mean has a "checked" property whose value is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing this is what you wanted.

```js
const data = [{Name: "foo", X1: "1", X2: "1", Other: "Test1"},{Name: "bar",
X1: "2",X2: "2",Other: "Test2"},{Name: "test",X1: "2",X2: "3",Other: "Test3"}
];
const fields = [{rows: {checked: true,value: "1",field: "X1"}
}, {rows: {checked: false,value: "2",field: "X1"}
}, {rows: {checked: true,value: "1",field: "X2"}
}, {rows: {checked: true,value: "2",field: "X2"}
}, {rows: {checked: true,value: "3",field: "X2"}
}];


const res = data.filter(d => !fields.find(f => d[f.rows.field] === f.rows.value && !f.rows.checked));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: EDITED: all X2 in fields should be false my bad, and still should output only "foo", only true matters and should disregard false.. it seems all false are not showing also..

Comment: its now working const res = data.filter(d => fields.find(f => d[f.rows.column] === f.rows.fields && f.rows.checked));